# Need to search for folders only, on the first Level Only

Tags: windows-7, windows, search, windows-search, file-search

First of all, I would like to ask if there is a possibility to get a more specific explanation as I am not a programmer.
Or maybe a software can be recommended (I've downloaded for example https://www.voidtools.com - "Everything Search Engine")

I wanted to know how to search only for folders, and only for folders, only for first Level folders in a certain Parent Folder, on a certain HDD (external). For convenience, I called that C: in this example.

For example:

The Parents Folder:

```
C:\ParentsFolder\
```

First Level Folders:

```
C:\ParentsFolder\A
C:\ParentsFolder\B
C:\ParentsFolder\C
```

Second Level Folders and the files in it:

```
C:\ParentsFolder\A\A\A.jpg
C:\ParentsFolder\A\B\B.jpg
C:\ParentsFolder\A\C\C.jpg
C:\ParentsFolder\B\A\A.jpg
C:\ParentsFolder\B\B\B.jpg
C:\ParentsFolder\B\C\C.jpg
C:\ParentsFolder\C\A\A.jpg
C:\ParentsFolder\C\B\B.jpg
C:\ParentsFolder\C\C\C.jpg
```

I want to search only what is inside `C:\ParentsFolder` without seeing what is inside the subfolders.

And If I search for "A" OR "B" OR "C", then I get:

```
C:\ParentsFolder\A\
C:\ParentsFolder\A\
C:\ParentsFolder\A\
C:\ParentsFolder\B\
C:\ParentsFolder\B\
C:\ParentsFolder\B\
C:\ParentsFolder\C\
C:\ParentsFolder\C\
C:\ParentsFolder\C\
```

**I don't want it to show the sub folders and the files.**

What I want to see in the results will actually be the folders themselves:

```
A
A
A 
B
B
B
C
C
C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with Windows search.

### +First Level Folders:

Type in the search field `foldername:ParentsFolder kind:folder A` will list all folders with name "A"

### +Second Level Folders and the files in it

You open folder "A" and type: `foldername:A A.jpg`

### And If I search for "A" OR "B" OR "C"

`foldername:ParentsFolder kind:folder A OR B OR C` ("OR" is case sensitive - has to be capital)

EDIT: if the folder has space in its name just put it into quotation marks `"..."` and it will work

Comment: Thanks Divin3

I am not sure it does the trick.

First of all - Where do I stand if I want to search the ParentsFolder? I think I need to be already inside the folder so how 'foldername:ParentsFolder' helps me?  I tried and it didn't work.   The folder's name (the ParentsFolder) is #Org and Unzipped (04-2016). Maybe there is a problem with the "#" in the name?

Comment: I noticed now that if I use spaces in foldername:, then it doesn't work. Only if I use one word from the folder's name. Is there a way to use the whole folder name?

Comment: Well, I got it. Still would like to know the way to include a full name of ParentsFolder when it has spaces, but I used just foldername:Unzipped kind:folder Finance, and it did find only the folders in the ParentsFolder and only the folders with that word in it, so it is a good solution for now :)

Comment: @OlegG - tell me exactly what do you want to serach for? If you want to look only in a given folder (no subfolders), use the 'foldername:' if you want to look only for folders, use the 'kind:folder' option. The search will always check only lower levels of the folder you started it from. It would be best to try it so you get the idea :)

Comment: @OlegG try quoting it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ffind](http://bvdsw.com/ffind/) Ext:

1. Type: d
2. Depth: 1

Directories only, first level:

[image]