# How to search only for folders in the search bar = Windows File Explorer Search Box of Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-search, file-search

I wonder what I am doing wrong or whether the search bar has changed. I need to make a search from the search bar of the Windows Explorer that puts out only folders. There is quite some rough research done up to now, which did not lead to a working outcome.

Super User SE:

- [How to search for directories only in Windows Explorer? [duplicate]](https://superuser.com/questions/1276790/how-to-search-for-directories-only-in-windows-explorer)
- [How to search for only folders in Windows 7 instead of folders AND files](https://superuser.com/questions/116514/how-to-search-for-only-folders-in-windows-7-instead-of-folders-and-files)
- [Need to search for folders only, on the first Level Only](https://superuser.com/questions/1067623/need-to-search-for-folders-only-on-the-first-level-only)

Serverfault SE:

- [search for just folders in windows explorer](https://serverfault.com/questions/26604/search-for-just-folders-in-windows-explorer)

Though it is likely that this is a (cross-site) duplicate, I still try this, since I did not find out what to do after some tries.

I tried:

```shell
kind:folder
kind:folders
* kind:folder
* kind:folders
kind:folder *
kind:folders *
folders
\d
```

But until now, the only way to get them is to search for `*.*` and get the folders at the beginning of the output of that.

How can I search only for directories that are in the directory that I am in, just with the search bar of the Windows File Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either by using the search options "Kind" dropdown

[image]

or in the search bar directly:

`kind:=folder`

(if you use the dropdown, it just adds that text to the search bar for you)

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick that is not in the search bar.

In the menu, choose `View` -> `Details`

Click on the Dropdown menu and checkmark "File folder"

[image]

Afterwards, you will see only folders in the directory that you are in. If you then search `*.*` in the search bar:

[image]

you will get only folders in the search output:

[image]

Countercheck:

[image]

Taken from [How to search for files, but not folders?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-search-for-files-but-not-folders/25d10083-722f-42c5-bc2c-1256dcfd0edb)